# RhinoException from mozilla's NativeJSON.parse does not have lineNumbers

Tags: error-handling, rhino, jsonparser

My java code reads a file containing json into a String, s, and calls `NativeJSON.parse(cx, scope, s, null)` which throws a RhinoException if the string is not proper json.  However, if the exception is thrown, calling the RhinoException object's `lineNumber()` method returns 0. Other useful attributes are also null or 0.

I have looked at the documentation and have had no joy.  Any suggestions?

- yes, there are new lines in s.
- There are methods to "init" line/column and source, but I only get access to the exception after it has been thrown.
- There is something called FEATURE_LOCATION_INFORMATION_IN_ERROR in the context, cx, but there is no way to set it by the looks of things.  I am obviously missing something.

(edit) Okay I have managed to get hasFeature( FEATURE_LOCATION_INFORMATION_IN_ERROR ) to return true by extending ContextFactory and overwriting hasFeature(..), but I still get no location information out of the RhinoException.

I think it is broken, and no longer used perhaps..

Answer (score 0):

Okay I solved it using the shotgun in the sports bag approach ...

```
/* Two days later.. 
  */ private int
findLine(JsonParser jp, String errmsg, List<String> lines) {
    for(int i= lines.size()-1; i>=0; --i) {
        String s = "";
        for(int j=0; j<i; j++) 
            s += lines.get(j);
        try{
            jp.parseValue(s);
        }catch(ParseException ex) {
            if(!errmsg.equals(ex.getMessage()))
               return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```